# Assigning names to a vector on instantiation

Tags: r, vector

For most base data structures in R it is possible to assign both the values and the names at the same time. For example:

```
l <- list(a=1:3, b=4)
m <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3, dimnames=list(letters[1:3], letters[1:3]))
d <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=letters[1:5], c=rnorm(5))
```

However for vectors this is different. As far as I know the only way to give `names` to a vector is afterwards:

```
v <- 1:3
names(v) <- letters[1:3]
```

`c` does not have arguments that allow you to specify the `names` at instantiation.
Trying to do it at assignment (like in `lists` or `data.frames`) also doesn't work:

```
v <- c("a"=1)  # error
```

Is it possible to assign both the data, and names of a vector at the same time?

Comment: But you didn't try it like you did when you created a list and a data.frame: `v <- c(a=1)` or `v <- setNames(1,"a")`

Comment: what error do you get when you run `c("a"=1)`?

Comment: Turns out i tried `c(letters[1:3]=1:3)` and that gave the error, but `c("a"=1)` works (and expansions of `c("a"=1, "b"=2, ...)`. But @JoshuaUlrich 's answer is much more convenient

Comment: @Manetheran, Why don't you just go ahead and write up an answer and accept it to show that there's an answer to this question.

Comment: Will do! I had written it off as a stupid question due to downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Joshua Ulrich answered in the comments, the correct answer is to use `setNames`:

```
v <- setNames(1:2, letters[1:2])
```

I'm also incorrect in my original question: `v <- c("a"=1)` works, however extending it is quite tedious: `v <- c("a"=1, "b"=2, ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another (uglier) solution is to use `structure()`

```
v <- structure(1:3, .Names = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

(I got here by looking at the results of `dput(v)` after
making it the hard way.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
for (n in 1:6) assign(x=letters[n], value=n)
```

produces:

```
> a
[1] 1
> b
[1] 2
> c
[1] 3
> d
[1] 4
> e
[1] 5
> f
[1] 6
```

Comment: That's not what he wants. He would like to create a named vector.

Comment: Ok. then the answer is @JoshuaUlrich 's: `sapply(c(1:6), setNames(x, letters[x]))`

Comment: No, the answer is `setNames(1:6, letters[1:6])`.

Comment: Sorry, i meant: `sapply(c(1:6), function(x){setNames(x, letters[x])})`

Comment: That still returns six vectors rather than one vector with six elements.

Comment: Both `setNames(1:6, letters[1:6])` and `sapply(c(1:6), function(x){setNames(x, letters[x])})` generate 1 named vector with 6 elements. Or is there something I'm still getting wrong?